# Métodos PUT e DELETE com o HttpStream?

Tags: java, totalcross

Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível utilizar o `HttpStream` com os métodos `PUT` e/ou `DELETE`?

```java
HttpStream.Options options = new HttpStream.Options();
options.setCharsetEncoding(HttpStream.Options.CHARSET_UTF8);
options.httpType = HttpStream.GET;
options.setContentType("application/json");

HttpStream httpStream = new HttpStream(new URI(VarGlobais.url), options);
```

no `HttpStream.Option` só é aceito `GET` e `POST`. Como faço para contornar isso?

Sei que o `HttpConn` possui essas opções de `PUT` e `DELETE`, porém ao utilizar o `HttpConn` no `WinCE` dá erro dizendo que não é encontrado a Classe `HttpConn`, por isso hoje estou usando o `HttpStream`.

Comment: A linguagem é Java ?

Comment: Sim, é Java utilizando a plataforma TotalCross

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do Javadoc (grifo meu):

> The default type is GET.
>   You can also define a custom type, like if you want to use restful services. In this case, the header will be set to what you store in the httpType String. Note that, to use another http method, **append a space**.

Exemplo com o método `PUT`:

> ```
> HttpStream.Options options = new HttpStream.Options();
> options.httpType = "PUT ";
> ```

Exemplo com um `CUSTOMMETHOD` qualquer:

> ```
> HttpStream.Options options = new HttpStream.Options();
> options.httpType = "CUSTOMMETHOD ";
> ```

Note os **espaços** entre o final do nome do método e o final da string.

Se você tem um método que não está descrito no `HttpStream` e quer indicar que envia dados, você precisa indicar isso no `Options`:

```
HttpStream.Options options = new HttpStream.Options();
options.httpType = "PUT ";
options.setSendData(true);
```

### Sobre o `HttpConn`

A classe `HttpConn` é um envólucro/*wrapper* sobre o `HttpStream`. Ele não fornece nenhuma funcionalidade a mais do que usar o `HttpStream` puro. Torna a vida muito mais fácil sim, mas é possível obter os mesmos resultados usando o `HttpStream`.

#### Classe `HttpConn` não encontrada?

Essa classe pertence a uma biblioteca. Para importar as bibliotecas no projeto, você precisa exportá-las como `.tcz` e colocar no `all.pkg` o nome do arquivo gerado.

---

## UPDATE

### Gerenciamento automático de dependências

A partir do TotalCross 4, demos suporte à geração automático dos `.tcz`s intermediários e gerência deles no `all.pkg`. Inclusive isso foi citado como um dos [destaques](https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-2017-07-31) de lançamento da versão.

Em tradução livre:

> - Deseja adicionar suas dependências automaticamente? Dê uma olhado no [`tc-compiler-help`](https://github.com/TotalCross/tc-compiler-help)
>
>   - O arquivo `all.pkg` é dinamicamente atualizado com suas dependências, retornando ao seu estado inicial ao fim da execção
> - Veja exemplos de *build*:
>
>   - *Build* para múltiplas platformas [aqui](https://github.com/TotalCross/IFoodUI/blob/c0e96ade3d24539fb2e96cae2637989c6aea5418/src/main/java/tc/samples/like/ifood/IFoodCompile.java#L12)
>   - Deve compilar com as dependências `magical-utils`, `tc-utilities` e `tc-components` [aqui](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross-big-file/blob/master/src/main/java/com/totalcross/sample/bigfile/BigFileCompile.java#L11)

Para habilitar o uso do `tc-compiler-help`, o primeiro passo é adicionar a dependência ao projeto:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.totalcross.utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>tc-compiler-help</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

> Para baixar corretamente essa dependência, é necessário usar o repositório Maven do TotalCross **OU** baixar o projeto `tc-compiler-help` na sua máquina

Para usar de fato o assistente de compilação, você deve começar criando um objeto do tipo [`CompilationBuilder`](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross-big-file/blob/76f6cd97d7e796f3585a9340321e72de1fdb94ef/src/main/java/com/totalcross/sample/bigfile/BigFileCompile.java#L10).

O `CompilationBuilder` atende (quase) às mesmas demandas que o `tc.Deploy` atende. Na verdade, `CompilationBuilder` vai fazer chamadas ao `tc.Deploy` de modo seguro/em *sandbox*. Você pode setar sua chave, setar qual é a classe principal, parâmetros de *build* alheios, definir plataformas, modificar as variáveis de ambiente antes da execução do `tc.Deploy` livremente.

> Os únicos casos em que o `tc.Deploy` apresenta funcionalidades que o `CompilationBuilder` não atende é para criar o `tcz` ou o executável a partir de um `.class` ou um `.zip`; mas isso não foi defeito, foi escolha de design, de modo que só permitimos assim criar `tcz`s e executáveis a partir de `.jar`.

Quase todos os métodos de configuração do `CompilationBuilder` retornam o próprio objeto. Isso permite fazer encadeamento de chamadas de métodos.

Além das configurações tradicionais de um *build* no TotalCross, você pode definir quais dependências que ele encontrar precisam ser compiladas para gerar o executável. Para fazer isso, basta chamar [`setMustCompile`](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross-big-file/blob/76f6cd97d7e796f3585a9340321e72de1fdb94ef/src/main/java/com/totalcross/sample/bigfile/BigFileCompile.java#L11) com uma função que vai julgar, baseado no caminho da dependência, se ela deve entrar no executável ou não.

Internamente, o `CompilationBuilder` passa todos os elementos do *classpath* para ser julgado pela função.

Para rodar esse `CompilationBuilder` em seu projeto:

1. crie uma classe com um método `public static void main; nesse método, você deve configurar o`CompilationBuilder`direta ou indiretamente; vamos chamar essa classe de`com.hello.world.ClasseCompilacao`;
2. rode `mvn clean package exec:java -Dexec:mainClass="com.hello.world.ClasseCompilacao"`

Comment: Jefferson, funcionou... Eu havia tentado colocando a String, mas não tinha concatenado com o espaço no fim. E sim, olhei no javadoc.. mas pelo menos aqui não tem essa parte dizendo para concatenar o espaço. Poderia confirmar se é esse link mesmo ou se estou olhando em algum javadoc desatualizado? (http://rs.totalcross.com/doc/totalcross/net/HttpStream.Options.html#httpType)

Comment: @DeivisonCardoso Realmente, está bem desatualizado esse Javadoc. Vou procurar atualizar para a última versão lançada